# Reading a text file encoded [ANSI] in C#

Tags: c#, windows, character-encoding

My text file contains chars like ö, ä, ü and the file is encoded in ANSI. I want to read it and put all data in a datatable. My code is:

```
    private DataTable GetTextToTable(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            int rowNo = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default,true))
            {
                DataRow dr = null;
                String line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    dr=dataTable.NewRow();
                    if (rowNo == 0)
                    {
                        string[] Columns = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        for (int i = 0; i != Columns.Length; i++)
                        {
                            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
                            dc.ColumnName = Convert.ToString(Columns[i]);
                            dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);
                        }
                        rowNo = rowNo + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string[] ColumnsValue = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        for (int i = 0; i != ColumnsValue.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = ColumnsValue[i];
                        }
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                }
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
              throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

And the output, I am getting from this code is: ¿½ for ö and in the same way getting arbitrary combination of chars for the rest ä, ü type chars also.
so help me! 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "ANSI" isn't one specific encoding. Lots of different encodings are often named as "ANSI" or (worse) "extended ASCII". You should find out the *exact* encoding of the file, and use that.

Comment: It sounds like the file is _actually_ UTF8, which uses multi-byte sequences.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, good link to peek at :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to download something like WinHex (which is free) that will let you look at the file in hexadecimal format which might help you find your problem.

This is just a guess but it sounds like your program is reading the raw hex and not being told to convert it to ASCII. **EDIT** Or whatever encoding format is used by the file you're reading from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers. @Jon Skeet sir, Can you please give me a link/help by using which I may find the exact encoding used in that text file which is saying ANSI encoded as in my example text file.